# PHP function not returning value

Tags: php, function, return

For some reason I can not get my function to return a string...

```
$password = crypt_password_input($password, "");

//Encrypt Password longer than 8 characters
function crypt_password_input($inputPassword, $newPassword)
{
    $passwordLength = strlen($inputPassword);

    if($passwordLength > 8){
        $encryptString = substr($inputPassword, 0, 8);
        $inputPassword = substr($inputPassword, 8);
        $newPassword .= crypt($encryptString, "HIDDENSALT");
        crypt_password_input($inputPassword, $newPassword);
    }else{
        $newPassword .= crypt($inputPassword, "HIDDENSALT");
        echo "Final: " . $newPassword . "<br/>";
        return $newPassword;
    }
}


echo "Encrypted from the input: " . $password . "<br/>";
```

This is the output of this script...

Final: ltu1GUwy71wHkltVbYX1aNLfLYltEZ7Ww8GghfM
Encrypted from the input:

Comment: acutally you return the string which is `ltu1GUwy71wHkltVbYX1aNLfLYltEZ7Ww8GghfM`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have no `return` statement under this condition block. i have added return there.

```
if($passwordLength > 8)
{
    $encryptString = substr($inputPassword, 0, 8);
    $inputPassword = substr($inputPassword, 8);
    $newPassword .= crypt($encryptString, "HIDDENSALT");
    return crypt_password_input($inputPassword, $newPassword);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your logic, but your code should be like this:

```
$password = crypt_password_input($password, "");

//Encrypt Password longer than 8 characters
function crypt_password_input($inputPassword, $newPassword)
{
    $passwordLength = strlen($inputPassword);

    if($passwordLength > 8)
    {
        $encryptString = substr($inputPassword, 0, 8);
        $inputPassword = substr($inputPassword, 8);
        $newPassword .= crypt($encryptString, "HIDDENSALT");
        return crypt_password_input($inputPassword, $newPassword);
    }
    else
    {
        $newPassword .= crypt($inputPassword, "HIDDENSALT");
        echo "Final: " . $newPassword . "<br/>";
        return $newPassword;
    }
}


echo "Encrypted from the input: " . $password . "<br/>";
```

In your code, you are recursively calling the input but not returning anything, so it fails if you have password longer than 8 characters.

Comment: He doesn't want it to return until the password has reached a length of 8 or more characters.

Comment: Yeah I did have $password = crypt_password_input($password, ""); for some reason I didn't write it here lol. I do see that I needed the return on the true condition. Thanks Guys :D